# IN Statement DynamoDB to get records where option could be of 4

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'm trying to do a scan on my Dynamodb and do a search on a field where the option can be 1 of 4 values. When I do the below I get no results, but when I search individually there are a number of records for each

```
TableName: 'TableName',
  FilterExpression:
   'dueDate IN (:option3, :option7, :option14, :option28)',
  ExpressionAttributeValues:
   { ':option3': '2019-07-03T00:00:00.000Z',
     ':option7': '2019-07-07T00:00:00.000Z',
     ':option14': '2019-07-14T00:00:00.000Z',
     ':option28': '2019-07-28T00:00:00.000Z' }
```

I dare say its something simple but I cant for the life of me work out what I've been doing wrong.

**Updated**

I don't get any errors in the logs, I just get no results.

Comment: please post a complete example. what is the actual "fieldName"? do you get any error? etc.

Comment: I'm not sure why this isn't working, but you can try several ORs and EQUALs

Comment: @Mojimi how do I the ORs? I could see any documentation on this.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html
just `dueDate = :option3 OR dueDate = :option7 OR ...`